# Accessory View Is Showing Up Half Off of the Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I cant figure out how to get my accessory view to fit into my cell.  Also,  When I add a subview it adds it to the right of the first subview added.  I want the sub views to be added from right to left.

I have this for my accessory view

```
UIView *myAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.accessoryView.frame];
```

And anytime I add a sub view I just write this

```
[myAccessoryView addSubview:greenCircle];
```

And as soon as it adds another subview it is placed to the right of the previous sub view which is even further off my cell. How do I reverse the way it adds subview?  How can I format the accessory view to stay on the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to init myAccessoryView with the frame of accessoryView that doesn't yet exist. It will be created after cell creation (and adding to tableView) if you specify cell.accessoryType property, or if you create and set accessoryView yourself like:

```
[cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryView];
```

So if You do this:

```
UIView *myAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.accessoryView.frame];
[cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryView];
```

You will have accessoryView with zero size and coordinates. After the cell is set to tableView, accessoryView will get standart origin point in the right side of the cell. But it still have zero size. And all subviews You add to accessoryView will be set to that origin point.

Method "addSubview" cant change subviews frame, it just places one view to another view.
Have no ideas why new subviews are placed to the rigtht of the previous.
To put your subviews to the right place, You have to set their frames manually. For example:

```
UIView *greenCircle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[myAccessoryView addSubview:greenCircle];
```

Hope that helps.